# how to remove back command from LWUIT

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I am trying to make an application using LWUIT Now i got a problem with back command from resource editor there are a back command in all forms and i cant find them in generated code

Can anyone please provide me reference or sample code for removing the Back command.

Answer (score 2):

Just invoke `setBackCommandEnabled(false)` in the state machine to disable the automatic back command navigation logic.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove back command only in some forms, you can do this in form where you want to remove:

```
Command backCommand = form.getBackCommand();
form.removeCommand(backCommand);
```